# Difficulty with double

Tags: c#, .net

The following line:

```
String itemid = reader1.IsDBNull(itemid_Index) ? null : reader1.GetString(itemid_Index);
```

gives me a runtime error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'

I have tried changing the line to this:

```
Double itemid = reader1.IsDBNull(itemid_Index) ? (Double?)null : reader1.GetDouble(itemid_Index);
```

but it gives the following design time error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'double?' to 'double'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Any ideas?

Comment: Make `itemid` a `Double?`? otherwise something like `reader1.GetDouble(itemid_Index) ?? null` or `reader1.GetDouble(itemid_Index).Value` (if you are certain that `GetDouble` won't return null)

Comment: `double` seems like an odd data type for an `index` column...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't assign a `null` to a `double`.  you either need to use `double?`:

```
Double? itemid = reader1.IsDBNull(itemid_Index) ? (Double?)null :  reader1.GetDouble(itemid_Index);
```

or use some other value to mean "null":

```
Double itemid = reader1.IsDBNull(itemid_Index) ? Double.MinValue : reader1.GetDouble(itemid_Index);
```

Comment: I withdraw my comment. I could have sworn I'd tried to do that before, and had the compiler yell at me.

Comment: @krillgar It is picky, but in this particular case it should work fine.